# barcode scanner always reads UPC-E

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am using zxing to implement a barcode scanner in my application . 
The issue is the scan result is always detecting UPC-E as the scan format and returning a wrong result. Any way to solve this ?

I am initiating the scan with the following code :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");//for Qr   code, its "QR_CODE_MODE" instead of "PRODUCT_MODE"
            intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);//this stops saving ur barcode in barcode scanner app's history
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

and the OnActivity block is as follows :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent    intent) 
{
if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Log.d("SEARCH_EAN", "OK, EAN: " + contents + ", FORMAT: " + format);//this is the result
        } else
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
```

Barcode scanner has been installed using Barcode-4.7.3.apk
Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not reading the barcode you want and finding a false positive first. You should specify the format you want to scan for in the Intent, since you don't even want to scan for UPC-E

Comment: In the ONE_D_CODE_TYPES variable i have specified the formats i want and i have removed UPC-E from that list , still it goes on to give the same result

Comment: Could this be because core.jar file is not properly integrated ?  i downloaded the jar file "core-3.2.0-sources.jar" from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.2.0/

Comment: No, you'd have much more obvious failures if you couldn't find classes. But you're integrating by Intent. You don't need any core.jar file. I think you're mixing up a few things.

Comment: Sorry , I am completely new to android but i can't figure out why is it reading UPC-E when the desired barcode format is set to CODE_128?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of things wrong with your example. First, you are adding core library code that you don't need, since you are integrating by `Intent`.

Second, for some reason you are invoking the scan twice. The second set of code does nothing. The camera param code also does nothing.

Third I think you're using a different project, not `zxing` for integration, since there is no `setDesiredBarcodeFormats` method in the project. Unless I'm forgetting this was in an old version or something.

Finally, you are scanning for all `ONE_D_CODE_TYPES` instead of the format you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I understood where i was going wrong . I changed the code (edited the question)  but the problem of scanning UPC-E still remains .

Comment: also i would like to add that the image is showing pretty blurred because of the front cam quality . i read a few posts about that being the reason .

Answer (score -1):

[github zbar code](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android)

use this code it works for me.